# Randomly sample N lines from two text files(parallel corpus) consistently

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file, command-line

Time and again, I'm faced with the problem of sampling a specific number of lines (let's say `N`) from two files (i.e. from a *parallel corpus*; the sentences are aligned according to line numbers) **consistently**.

This is a common and frequent task for anyone doing research in (Neural) Machine Translation.

I would like to know a fast and effective way to sample (i.e. select) *`N`* lines from a parallel corpus, possibly from command-line.

For example, if we want to choose `4` lines from two files in a consistent manner, we could sample lines at line numbers `3`, `12`, `17`, `23`. This should give us these lines from both files. Also, it would be nice to have this parameter `N` as arbitrary so that we can change it as we like to do so. Further, these lines should be sampled *without repetition*. And, the required number of lines `N` that need to be sampled will always be less than the total lines in both files, where both files will always have the equal number of lines in total.

Once we sample the required lines, it's also desirable to get the lines from both files which has not been sampled (i.e. get the rest of the lines which has not been selected in the random sampling).

> The whole idea of doing this is to sample two files in a consistent manner such that their line-alignments are preserved. (i.e. choose `N` lines and `N-T` lines where `T` is the total number of lines.)

where `N` is the desired number of lines to be sampled without repetition and `N-T` is the rest of the lines which has not been sampled.

How would I go about doing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: with repetition or without?  Can the same line be sampled more than once.  Also is it given that the files line size are greater than N?

Comment: @karakfa without repetition! The required number of lines `N` that needs to be sampled will always be less than the total lines in both files :). Also, both files will have the same number of lines. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't allow repetition, it's better to use a shuffle algorithm.  There is already a tool `shuf` for this purposes.

For example,

```
$ shuf -n 10 file
```

will give you 10 randomly selected lines from the file (in a random order).  Your request have two additional constraints,  first the selection should be sorted, second the selection needs to be consistent for another run.  For the second requirement you can provide the randomness source to `shuf` to get the same sequence twice.  For sorting we are on our own...

```
$ shuf -n 10 --random-source=file <(cat -n file1) | sort -n | cut -f2- > sample1
$ shuf -n 10 --random-source=file <(cat -n file2) | sort -n | cut -f2- > sample2
```

will give you the same sampled lines in the right order.  For randomness you can use either file or any other third file (but should be the same for both runs).

Another alternative is to paste the two files together and do the shuffle once and split the samples after.

```
$ paste -d'|' file1 file2 | cat -n | shuf -n 10 | sort -n | cut -f2 > sample

$ cut -d'|' -f1 sample > sample1
$ cut -d'|' -f2 sample > sample2
```

to get the not selected lines you need to preserve the line numbers.  Using the second alternative

```
$ paste -d'|' file1 file2 | cat -n | shuf -n 10 | sort -n > n_samples
$ cut -f2- n_samples > samples
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} !(FNR in a)' <(cut -f1 n_samples) samples > notselected
```

and you can split both samples and notselected files as before.

Using the first alternative, non selected lines from files will be written to files with the same name and extension ".not"

```
$ cat -n file1 | shuf -n 10 --random-source=file | sort -n > n_sample1
$ cut -f2- n_sample1 > sample1
$ cat -n file2 | shuf -n 10 --random-source=file | sort -n | cut -f2- > sample2
$ awk 'NR==FNR    {a[$1];next} 
      !(FNR in a) {print > FILENAME".not"}' <(cut -f1 n_sample1) sample1 sample2
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there an easy way to also get the lines from both files which has not been sampled ? i.e. **get** the **rest of the lines** which has not been chosen in the random sampling.

Comment: Thanks! I find the first approach more straightforward than the second. Isn't it possible to get the not-selected lines using first approach?

Comment: yes, do the same thing; save the line numbered samples after `sort -n` and extract line numbers as shown.  You just need this once, since both line numbers will be identical.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, would you mind adding this as well in the answer? :)

Comment: Updated but again not tested.  Please verify and comment here.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
samples=$1
file1="$2"
file2="$3"

maxlines=$(cat "$file1" | wc -l)
nums=($(shuf -e $(echo $(seq 1 $maxlines))))
lines=$(for i in $(seq 1 $samples); do echo ${nums[$i]}p" "; done | sort -n)
sed -n "$lines" "$file1"
sed -n "$lines" "$file2"

#rows1=($(sed -n "$lines" "$file1"))
#rows2=($(sed -n "$lines" "$file2"))
```

- Parameters $1,2,3: Number of samples, filename1 and 2.
- maxline with wc -l and cat, because then we needn't strip of the filename. (no useless use of cat award, here).
- seq x y generates a sequence from x to y, here 1 to maxlines. No off-by-one error, because wc, the source, counts from 1 as sed does (later).
- shuf -e shuffles the numbers, without -e expecting them rowwise
- for the count of samples, pull linenumbers from the front,

  - but sort them, so that sed only has to traverse the files once.
  - the postfix 'p 'is for sed.
- sed -n, for a small file of 11 lines, sample=4, looks like this:

  sed -n 3p 
   4p 
   5p 
   7p  mul.sh

If you don't want the output filewise, but rowwise, collect them in arrays:

```
rows1=($(sed -n "$lines" "$file1"))
rows2=($(sed -n "$lines" "$file2"))
```

This way, sed still has to traverse the probably large files only once. With an array index from 0 to $sample-1 you can iterate over the two row arrays and compare them - or whatever the job is.